# Using alternation and grouping constructs

Tags: c#, regex

Originally I wanted a regex parsing month numbers. At first I came up with the following regex:

```
^([1-9]{1})|(1[012])$
```

and it matched any positive number, saying that it matched the high-order digit of the number, i.e.:

```
1 => 1
2 => 2
...
9 => 9
10=> 1
...
19=> 1
20=> 2
...
```

Why is that so? I thought that the alternation construct will make `Regex` choose either the left one or the right, while having `^` and `&` makes it match the whole string. What am I missing?

P.S.: I do have a working regex now (one that matches numbers from 1 to 12 only); it's:

```
^([1-9]{1}|1[012])$
```

And I can't catch why it works so....

This is the code I used to test:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^([1-9]{1})|(1[012])$");//^([1-9]{1}|1[012])$
for (int i = -5; i < 35; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i);
    Console.Write("\t");
    Match m = r.Match(i.ToString());
    if (m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("false");
}
```

Comment: I like using `Expresso` to work with Regex. It's an easy-to-use tool that lets you build, evaluate and test expressions against test sample text. http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: @retailcoder thanks, I'll have a look at it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the first regular expression like this:

```
^([1-9]{1})      # match this
|                # ...OR...
(1[012])$        # match this
```

Either match a digit 1-9 at the beginning of the string and store that in group #1, or match 10-12 at the end of the string and store that in group #2.

The first successful match is used, so when you match against `10` the `^([1-9]{1})` part of the regex matches. You can see why `20` is a match with this broken regex.

Also, you print out only group #1's contents and ignore group #2's. So if the second set of parentheses had happened to match, you wouldn't see that in your printout.

```
if (m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

Your second regex fixes the problem by surrounding the two `|` alternatives with parentheses, leaving the `^` and `$` anchors on the outside, and leaving only one set of parentheses so the result is always in group #1.

And for what it's worth, the `{1}` is unnecessary. You could write:

```
^([1-9]|1[012])$
```

Comment: So, this would work as expected `^([1-9])$|^(1[012])$`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would, but you would have to look in two different capture groups. A 1-digit month will be in group 1, a 2-digit month will be in group 2. The RE in the answer will put the matched month in group 1 regardless of whether it's one or two digits.

Answer (score 2):

[The alternation operator has the lowest precedence of all regex operators.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

The difference between the two regular expressions, interpreted literally, is this:

```
( [BEGIN]([1-9]) )    OR    ( (1[012])[END] )
```

vs

```
[BEGIN] ( [1-9]    OR    1[012] ) [END]
```

Comment: +1, but please drop the `{1}`.  I know it doesn't hurt anything, and I know you just copied it from the OP's own regex, and but by including it in your answer you unintentionally encourage other regex neophytes to believe it does something useful.